# Shorter way to write this regex?

Tags: regex

```
/[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9-]*/
```

Is there a shorter more concise way to write this?

Comment: Are you sure you want to match strings ending with a hyphen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `i` modifier to make it case-insensitive, so you don't have to write both `A-Z` and `a-z`. And you can replace `0-9` with `\d`.

```
/[a-z][a-z\d-]*/i
```

There's no escape sequence that just matches letter, or letters, numbers and hyphen. The closest is `\w`, which matches letter, numbers, and underscore.